# How to make a custom datetimepicker in c#.net

Tags: c#, custom-controls, datetimepicker

I have created a custom control called MyDateTime as a datetimepicker in c#.net. it builds successful and it runs ok.but when I click on the button it freezes.I must display a panel on below but it does not.I check the code and it is ok .Apparently there is a runtim e error .please help me to solve it

code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class MyDateTime : UserControl
    {
        private Button DropButton;
        private MaskedTextBox maskedTextBox1;
        private MonCal monCal = null;
        public class MonCalEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            private DateTime selectedDate;

            public MonCalEventArgs(DateTime sentSelectedDate)
            {
                selectedDate = sentSelectedDate;
            }

            public string SelectedDate { get { return selectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); } }
        }

        public class HighlightedDates
        {
            public DateTime Date;
            public Point Position = new Point(0, 0);
            public Color DateColor;
            public Color BoxColor;
            public Color BackgroundColor;
            public Boolean Bold;

            public HighlightedDates(DateTime date)
            {
                this.Date = date;
                this.DateColor = this.BoxColor = this.BackgroundColor = Color.Empty;
                this.Bold = true;
            }

            public HighlightedDates(DateTime date, Color dateColor, Boolean bold)
            {
                this.Date = date;
                this.BackgroundColor = this.BoxColor = Color.Empty;
                this.DateColor = dateColor;
                this.Bold = bold;
            }

            public HighlightedDates(DateTime date, Color dateColor, Color boxColor,
                Color backgroundColor, Boolean bold)
            {
                this.Date = date;
                this.DateColor = dateColor;
                this.BoxColor = boxColor;
                this.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
                this.Bold = bold;
            }
        }


        public MyDateTime()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SuspendLayout();

            maskedTextBox1 = new MaskedTextBox();
            maskedTextBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000";
            maskedTextBox1.Name = "maskedTextBox1";
            maskedTextBox1.Size = new Size(139, 20);
            maskedTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            maskedTextBox1.ValidatingType = typeof(DateTime);

            DropButton = new Button();
            DropButton.Size = new Size(16, 16);
            DropButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
            DropButton.BackColor = Color.White;
            DropButton.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\JAVAD\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\CalendarIcon.ico");
            DropButton.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Tile;
            DropButton.Location = new Point(maskedTextBox1.Width - 20, 0);
            DropButton.Click += new EventHandler(DropButton_Click);
            DropButton.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            maskedTextBox1.Controls.Add(DropButton);
            maskedTextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyy");

            this.Controls.Add(maskedTextBox1);

            this.ResumeLayout();
            // InitializeComponent();
        }
        void DropButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string a= maskedTextBox1.Text;
            string []aa= a.Split('/');
            List<HighlightedDates> hlDates = new List<HighlightedDates>();
            hlDates.Add(new HighlightedDates(new DateTime(int.Parse(aa[2]), int.Parse(aa[0]), int.Parse(aa[1])),
                Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Pink, true));

            monCal = new MonCal(hlDates);
            monCal.monCalControlHandler +=
                new MonCal.MonCalControlHandler(monCal_monCalControlHandler);
            monCal.Location = new Point(20, 20);
            this.Controls.Add(monCal);
        }

        void monCal_monCalControlHandler(object sender, MonCalEventArgs e)
        {
            maskedTextBox1.Text = e.SelectedDate;
            this.Controls.Remove(monCal);
            monCal = null;
        }

        internal class MonCal : MonthCalendar
        {
            protected static int WM_PAINT = 0x000F;
            private Rectangle dayBox;
            private int dayTop = 0;
            private SelectionRange range;

            private List<HighlightedDates> highlightedDates;

            public delegate void MonCalControlHandler(object sender, MonCalEventArgs e);
            public event MonCalControlHandler monCalControlHandler;

            public MonCal(List<HighlightedDates> HighlightedDates)
            {
                this.ShowTodayCircle = false;
                this.highlightedDates = HighlightedDates;
                range = GetDisplayRange(false);
                SetDayBoxSize();
                SetPosition(this.highlightedDates);

            }

            private void SetDayBoxSize()
            {
                int bottom = this.Height;

                while (HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
                    HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.PrevMonthDate) dayTop++;

                while (HitTest(1, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
                    HitTest(1, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.NextMonthDate) bottom--;

                dayBox = new Rectangle();
                dayBox.Size = new Size(this.Width / 7, (bottom - dayTop) / 6);
            }

            private void SetPosition(List<HighlightedDates> hlDates)
            {
                int row = 0, col = 0;

                hlDates.ForEach(delegate (HighlightedDates date)
                {
                    if (date.Date >= range.Start && date.Date <= range.End)
                    {
                        TimeSpan span = date.Date.Subtract(range.Start);
                        row = span.Days / 7;
                        col = span.Days % 7;
                        date.Position = new Point(row, col);
                    }
                });
            }

            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
                {
                    Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
                    PaintEventArgs pea =
                        new PaintEventArgs(g, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
                    OnPaint(pea);
                }
            }

            protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
            {
                base.OnPaint(pe);

                Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
                Rectangle backgroundRect;

                highlightedDates.ForEach(delegate (HighlightedDates date)
                {
                    backgroundRect = new Rectangle(
                                date.Position.Y * dayBox.Width + 1,
                                date.Position.X * dayBox.Height + dayTop,
                                dayBox.Width, dayBox.Height);

                    if (date.BackgroundColor != Color.Empty)
                    {
                        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(date.BackgroundColor))
                        {
                            g.FillRectangle(brush, backgroundRect);
                        }
                    }

                    if (date.Bold || date.DateColor != Color.Empty)
                    {
                        using (Font textFont =
                            new Font(Font, (date.Bold ? FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular)))
                        {
                            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, date.Date.Day.ToString(), textFont,
                                backgroundRect, date.DateColor,
                                TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
                        }
                    }

                    if (date.BoxColor != Color.Empty)
                    {
                        using (Pen pen = new Pen(date.BoxColor))
                        {
                            Rectangle boxRect = new Rectangle(
                             date.Position.Y * dayBox.Width + 1,
                                date.Position.X * dayBox.Height + dayTop,
                                dayBox.Width, dayBox.Height);
                            g.DrawRectangle(pen, boxRect);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
            protected override void OnDateSelected(DateRangeEventArgs drevent)
            {
                base.OnDateSelected(drevent);
                MonCalEventArgs args = new MonCalEventArgs(drevent.Start);
                monCalControlHandler(this, args);
                this.Dispose();
            }
            protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
            {
                base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it so you can give us a bit more specific details, where the program freezes? I assume it's stuck inside the `SetDayBoxSize` method.

Comment: I have encountered no error just it freezes

Comment: I haven't said you have an error but whenever your program freezes it most likely means it's stuck because of a heavy operation, or an endless cycle which seems more likely here.

Comment: can you please run it as a c# project and find the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your program is stuck inside:

> ```
> while (HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
>         HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.PrevMonthDate) dayTop++;
>
> while (HitTest(1, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
>         HitTest(1, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.NextMonthDate) bottom--;
> ```

That's because `HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea` returns a value of `HitArea.Nowhere`. that means all of your conditions in the while loops will be always right, thus causing the program to freeze because it's stuck there looping mindlessly forever.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but a simple fix would be to add the following line to your while loops:

```
while (HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.Nowhere &&
       HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
       HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.PrevMonthDate)
{
    dayTop++;
}

while (HitTest(1, dayTop).HitArea != HitArea.Nowhere &&
       HitTest(1, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.Date &&
       HitTest(1, bottom).HitArea != HitArea.NextMonthDate)
{
    bottom--;
}
```

Comment: how did you find the stuck

Comment: @Shayan As I explained in my comment under your question, your program will freeze, because it's currently busy. You see that your program is freezing when you press the button, you should take a look at the place where you handle the click event. After that start looking for any heavy operation, if there are none, than that means it's most likely stuck in some endless loop which is caused by not well thought condition, in your case the while loops.

Comment: @Shayan If my answer resolved your issue, please consider accepting by pressing the circle check mark under the down-vote icon.